# how to add space between a string in python. I am fetching the data from ms access database

Tags: python, django, ms-access

```
def buildprofilepage(result):
    data = {"Street": str(result[11]).replace("_", " "), "City": str(result[12]).replace("_", " "),
        "State": result[13], "Street1": str(result[16]).replace("_", " "),"City1": str(result[17]).replace("_", " ")}
    return data
```

In place of underscore I want to display space between string. But every time I try it, it displays only the first few character then spaces.

Comment: Can you add a sample i/o?

Answer (score 0):

Right now your str.replace should do something like shown in this little Python Shell example.

```
>>> str = "Hello_World_to_Amit"
>>> str.replace(""," ")
' H e l l o _ W o r l d _ t o _ A m i t '
```

But if you want to replace a Space with an Underscore you have to specify it in the replace string like this:

```
>>> str = "Hello_World_to_Amit"
>>> str.replace("_"," ") #Here, I specified the old string as "_" to replace
'Hello World to Amit'
```

Describes that your problem?
If not, feel free to specify your Problem a little more, to get more accurate help

With kind regards

Comment: In python console it shows correct output but using the same program by python with django framework it show only first few characters before underscore(_) then it displays space